# How to integrate CSS-Framework and inline styles in GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I would like to use the css framework https://github.com/bonsaicss/bonsai.css together with [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/). I am currently looking at how to do this with a default starter.

So far I have managed to install the framework `npm install bonsai.css` and integrate it into my page `import "../../node_modules/bonsai.css/dist/bonsai.css".` I hope this is the right way in Gatsby?

Also I can use classes via `<h1 className="primary">` and this works well.

But: I have to insert inline styles like this `<div class="grid" style="--col:3">`. Here is a link to an example page:
https://github.com/bonsaicss/bonsai.css/blob/4a3410a01b839960f35bd7d72437eeb5273465e4/index.html#L73

I tried it like this `<div className="grid" style={{"--col:3"}}>` but this failed to compile.

I have no idea, how I can realize this in Gatsby. I would be happy if someone could give me a hint.

I also opened a discussion for this topic [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/27808).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you should ask a question after a pause. The solution just occurred to me while walking the dog. I forgot two quotation marks:

```
<div className="grid" style={{"--col":"3"}}>

"--col  "  :  "  3"
```